# Jetpack Compose Navigation: How do I navigate between composables of a nested nav graph?

Tags: android, jetpack-compose-navigation

Consider the following Jetpack Compose Navigation graph:

```
<root>
  a
    x
    y
  b
    x
    y
```

Here, `a` and `b` are nested nav graphs created using `navigation(startDestination = "x", route = ROUTE)` where `ROUTE` is `a` or `b` respectively. Both of these nested nav graphs have composables `x` and `y` inside them.

Let's assume we're currently in route `b/y`, that is the screen `y` inside nested nav graph `b`. The user wants to navigate to `b/x`. I tried this by calling `navController.navigate("x")`, having assumed that it would first search the nested graph the user is currently in (`b`). But it turns out that Compose Navigation scans the full nav graph top to bottom for a composable matching `x`, so it finds `a/x`.

What call to `navController.navigate(...)` do I have to make to navigate from `b/y` to `b/x`?

Here's the full sample:

```kotlin
NavHost(navController, startDestination = "b") {
    navigation(startDestination = "x", route = "a") {
        composable("x") {
            Text(text = "We're in a/x")
            Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("y") }) {
                Text("Go to y")
            }
        }
        composable("y") {
            Text(text = "We're in a/y")
            Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("x") }) {
                Text("Go to x")
            }
        }
    }
    navigation(startDestination = "y", route = "b") {
        composable("x") {
            Text(text = "We're in b/x")
            Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("y") }) {
                Text("Go to y")
            }
        }
        composable("y") {
            Text(text = "We're in b/y")
            Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("x") }) {
                Text("Go to x")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made a complete nested navigation example you can find it here. https://medium.com/@chiragthummar16/jetpack-compose-nested-navigation-best-practices-978b066c1fb1

Comment: @ChiragThummar Unfortunately that example also assumes all composables across all nested nav graphs have unique names. My situation is that the nested graphs contain composables with the same names.

Comment: You can not have same name for composable.

Answer (score -1):

I have added the parent graph's route ("a" or "b") before specifying the child graph's route ("x" or "y") when navigating between composables. This is essential because each nested graph is treated as a separate stack of composables.

```
        NavHost(navController, startDestination = "b") {
            navigation(startDestination = "x", route = "a") {
                composable("x") {
                    Text(text = "We're in a/x")
                    Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("a/y") }) {
                        Text("Go to a/y")
                    }
                }
                composable("y") {
                    Text(text = "We're in a/y")
                    Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("a/x") }) {
                        Text("Go to a/x")
                    }
                }
            }
            navigation(startDestination = "x", route = "b") {
                composable("x") {
                    Text(text = "We're in b/x")
                    Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("b/y") }) {
                        Text("Go to b/y")
                    }
                }
                composable("y") {
                    Text(text = "We're in b/y")
                    Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("b/x") }) {
                        Text("Go to b/x")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Prefixing the destination argument with `b/` results in this error: 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/b/y } cannot be found in the navigation graph ComposeNavGraph(0x0) startDestination={ComposeNavGraph(0xe5901275) route=b startDestination={Destination(0xe590128b) route=x}}`